# Stack Overflow "light" script?

Tags: feature-request, design, scripts

I'd love a Stack Overflow light version. You could probably achieve this with a CSS document.

I'd want all "clutter" removed. The whole bar to right for example. Also, removing the count for favorites, up and down voting etc.

You can keep the vote up/down buttons, but remove details such as how many votes it has had.

Am I the only one who would love a version where you only can: search, see and answer questions? No other details.

Comment: I was gonna answer disable all the stylesheets, but apparently SO doesn't use semantic HTML especially in certain page areas, so it looks very broken.

Comment: You are the only one! Get Firefox, look at the add-ons, do it yourself.

Comment: stack overflow is a pretty "lite" site to begin with. this is the kind of thing that firefox extensions are invented for.

Comment: you mean like, mobile version of SO so that the overall size would be less? Yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you're the *only* one but I don't find all that so-called "clutter" gratuitous or unnecessary.

Most of the "meta data" surrounding the posts provide important context (for me, anyway). Voting indicates the apparent correctness/vetting of the information. "Related questions" might give me an important clue to finding more information. Flair gives me a visual cue about who's talking about what... Sure, I might not *always* care about the number of viewers... until I do. It might tell me why a question doesn't seem to have the *best* answers, yet (low readership).

All that "clutter" makes the experience much more immersive for me. That's how I learn. It's a whole "concepts of cyberspace" thing; making a *personal connection* with something that, in reality, is little more than a big heaping pile of text.